# Multiple Files Uploading in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have been trying to upload multiple files in Laravel. There are few solutions to this problem in Stackoverflow, but none works for me.

This is my store method:

```
public function bulkstore(Request $request)
    {
        foreach ($request->file_name as $file) {

            if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
                $fileNameWithExt = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
                $fileName = pathinfo($fileNameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                $extenstion = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $fileNameToStore = $fileName.'.'.$extenstion;
                $path = $request->file('file')->storeAs('public/images', $fileNameToStore);
            }

            File::create([
                'file_name' => $fileNameToStore,
            ]);
        }

        return redirect('/file');
    }
```

I am getting this error:

> Undefined variable: fileNameToStore

This method works for single file, but not for multiple file. Any suggestion?

Comment: have you tried different if statment?, the block where variable is created. as well you should deal with $file not $request->file('file') in a loop

Comment: Tested with $file only. getting same error. any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this

```
$files = $request->file('file');
if($request->hasFile('file'))
{
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $fileNameWithExt = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $fileName = pathinfo($fileNameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $extenstion = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileNameToStore = $fileName.'.'.$extenstion;
        $path = $file->storeAs('public/images', $fileNameToStore);
        File::create([
            'file_name' => $fileNameToStore,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome my friend :)